# Drawing equally-sized samples from differently-sized substrata of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sample

I have a dataframe with multiple columns containing, inter alia, words and their position in sentences. For some positions, there's more rows than for other positions. Here's a mock example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  word = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T),
  position = sample(1:5, 100, replace = T)
)
head(df)
  word position
1    K        1
2    R        5
3    J        2
4    Y        5
5    Z        5
6    U        4
```

Obviously, the tranches of 'position' are differently sized:

```
table(df$position)
 1  2  3  4  5 
15 15 17 28 25
```

To make the different tranches more easily comparable I'd like to draw equally sized samples on the variable 'position' within one dataframe. This can theoretically be done in steps, such as these:

```
df_pos1 <- df[df$position==1,]
df_pos1_sample <- df_pos1[sample(1:nrow(df_pos1), 3),]

df_pos2 <- df[df$position==2,]
df_pos2_sample <- df_pos2[sample(1:nrow(df_pos2), 3),]

df_pos3 <- df[df$position==3,]
df_pos3_sample <- df_pos3[sample(1:nrow(df_pos3), 3),]

df_pos4 <- df[df$position==4,]
df_pos4_sample <- df_pos4[sample(1:nrow(df_pos4), 3),]

df_pos5 <- df[df$position==5,]
df_pos5_sample <- df_pos5[sample(1:nrow(df_pos5), 3),]
```

and so on, to finally combine the individual samples in a single dataframe:

```
df_samples <- rbind(df_pos1_sample, df_pos2_sample, df_pos3_sample, df_pos4_sample, df_pos5_sample)
```

but this procedure is cumbersome and error-prone. A more economical solution might be a for loop. I've tried this code so far, which, however, returns, not a combination of the individual samples for each position value but a single sample drawn from all values for 'position':

```
df_samples <-c()
for(i in unique(df$position)){
   df_samples <- rbind(df[sample(1:nrow(df[df$position==i,]), 3),])
}
df_samples
   word position
13    D        2
2     R        5
12    G        3
4     Y        5
16    Z        3
11    S        3
6     U        4
14    J        3
9     O        5
1     K        1
```

What's wrong with this code and how can it be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `by` to split data frame by *position* with needed sampling. Then `rbind` all dfs together outside the loop with `do.call()`.

```
df_list <- by(df, df$position, function(sub) sub[sample(1:nrow(sub), 3),])

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Currently you index the entire (not subsetted) data frame in each iteration. Also, you are using `rbind` inside a `for` loop which is memory-intensive and not advised.

Specifically,

- `by` is the object-oriented wrapper to `tapply` and essentially splits a data frame into subsets by factor(s) and passes each subset into a defined function. Here *sub* is just the name of subsetted variable (can be named anything). The result here is a list of data frames.
- `do.call` essentially runs a compact version of an expanded call across multiple elements where `rbind(df1, df2, df3)` is equivalent to `do.call(rbind, list(df1, df2, df3))`. The key here to note is `rbind` is not called inside a loop (avoiding the danger of growing complex objects like a data frame inside an iteration) but *once* outside the loop.

Comment: Could you maybe comment on the key elements of the code such as 'by', 'sub', and 'do-call'? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` with a group by `sample` of the row index `.I` and use that to subset the dataset.  This would be very efficient

```
i1 <- setDT(df)[, sample(.I, 3), position]$V1
df[i1]
```

---

Or use `sample_n` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(position) %>% 
   sample_n(3)
```

---

Or as a function

```
f1 <- function(data) {
     data as.data.table(data)
     i1 <- data[, sample(.I, 3), by = position]$V1
     data[i1]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you run the loop you are overwriting the last entry. Try:

```
df_samples <- data.frame()
df_samples <- rbind(df_samples, df[sample(1:nrow(df[df$position==i,]), 3),])
```